# Bell numbers and a card shuffle

Tags: combinatorics, bell-numbers

A deck of *n* cards  may be 'shuffled' by moving the top card to any (random) position in the deck, and performing this operation *n* times. Martin Gardner asserts (Scientific American, May 1978) that the number of such shuffles that return the deck to its original state is equal to the *n*th Bell number. This appears to be true for the first few cases but I have not been able to explain why it should be so for all *n*.
A set partition that corresponds to the problem seems hard to find. Symmetric groups offer some insights but nothing conclusive, so far.

Comment: Can you clarify what the operation is? If we always just move the top card to the same position $k$, aren't we just cycling the top $k$ cards?

Comment: Karl: correct - this would be one way of returning the deck to its original state.

Comment: Brian: Only n moves are allowed.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott A shuffle is defined to be a sequence of $n$ integers $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$, each between $1$ and $n$. To perform this shuffle, during the $i^{th}$ stage for $i=1,2,\dots,n$, move the top card of the deck to position $i$ while maintaining the relative ordering of the other cards. The question is, for how many sequences does the shuffle return the deck to its initial state? For example, when $n=2$, the sequences $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$ will return the deck to its initial state, so the answer is $2$ (indeed equal to the second Bell number).

Comment: @Mike: (I think that you mean to move the top card to position $a_i$.) Yes, I finally realized that I completely misread the assertion.

Answer (score 5):

It is slightly more convenient to consider the shuffles "played backwards", with each move taking an arbitrary card to the top of the deck. Then we're still counting shuffles (call them *neutral*) that leave the deck in its initial state when played.

Let's label the cards by (elements of) $[n]:=\{1,\ldots,n\}$, and let the initial state of the deck be $(1,\ldots,n)$. Then any (not only neutral) shuffle is uniquely determined by $\ell=(\ell_1,\ldots,\ell_n)$, where $\ell_k$ is (the label of) the card that is moved to the top at step $k$.

Now, to each neutral shuffle, we assign the partition of $[n]$ into the equivalence classes of the relation $j\sim k\iff\ell_j=\ell_k$. This is reversed as follows: let $[n]=N_1\cup\ldots\cup N_m$ be a partition of $[n]$, with $N_1,\ldots,N_m$ ordered so that $j\mapsto\max N_j$ is decreasing; then, we set $\ell_k=j$ iff $k\in N_j$.

The order of $N_j$ ensures that the latter gives a *neutral* shuffle (in the resulting deck, the card $1$ will be on top because it is moved last, and so on upto the card $m$; the remaining cards (if any) are not used, so these go to the bottom, with their order unchanged). It is also clear that different partitions map to different $\ell$'s.